# xgboost install failed in Python on Mac at zsh terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, xgboost, macos-catalina

Error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/strings.h:85:17: error: expected initializer before '__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING'
     int  ffsl(long) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

Full Error:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4933

This is not working after update to Catalina. Before that it was okey.

Answer (score -3):

Open up Xcode, and accept the new user agreement. This was happening because a new version of Xcode was downloaded and the new agreement was not accepted.